# Shortcuts-app automation to prevent iPhone screen from going to sleep

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake, automation, shortcuts-app

I was recently playing around a bit with the new Shortcuts app on the iPhone.

Is there an action to "prevent screen from going to sleep". Ideally, I'd want to activate it when a certain app is running. While the condition is easy to set, I can't find any way to then assign a "prevent sleeping" action.

Comment: How would you accomplish „prevent sleep“ manually (without Shortcuts)?

Comment: @nohillside Manually I have to use the Display/Brightness setting "Auto-Lock" to "Never".

Answer (score 6):

The closest you can currently do is to automatically open the correct settings screen using `Shortcuts`. This can be achieved by creating an URL and opening it in Safari:

```
prefs:root=DISPLAY&path=AUTOLOCK
```

This will open the settings accordingly in the right place.

[image: Action Setting]

More URL schemes can be found here: [A Comprehensive Guide to All 120+ Settings URLs Supported by iOS and iPadOS 13.1](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/).

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, I'd use combination of Low-power mode and Auto-Lock after t time.

In Display and Brightness Settings, you can set auto-lock to 1-5 minutes or never. Now since this might drain battery, use low power mode when your "condition is not met". This locks the auto-lock timer to 30 seconds.

Low power mode has its own cons, like some syncs disabled, reduced brightness etc.

Comment: This is genius!